# What did I just do? Memory leak in C++?

Tags: c++, memory

Not sure what I did /  didn't do, but it has given me crazy results!

Here is the code...

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int counter = 0;
int trigger = 0;

int main(){
    while(1)
    {
    if (counter == trigger)
       {
       cout << "Beep\n" + counter;
       counter = 0;
       trigger = (rand() % 20000000);
       }
    counter++;
   }
return 0;
}
```

Seems pretty simple right? Run it and see what happens!

I get an audible tone out of my speakers and greeted with this...

[image]

Any ideas??

-Adrian

Comment: `cout << "Beep\n" + counter;` What is this supposed to do?

Comment: You should probably better write `cout << "Beep\n" << counter;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`"Beep\n" + counter` causes `"Beep\n"` to decay to a pointer to the first char `'B'` and offset that pointer by `counter`.

For example,

- if `counter = 0`, `"Beep\n" + 0` evaluates to `"Beep\n"`,
- if `counter = 1`, `"Beep\n" + 1` evaluates to `"eep\n"` (pointing to the second char),
- if `counter = 2`, `"Beep\n" + 2` evaluates to `"ep\n"`,
- etc.

until you read memory that's not yours after `counter > 4`.

That's not a memory leak, that's **undefined behavior**.

Answer (score 4):

This statement

```
cout << "Beep\n" + counter;
```

has undefined behaviour when `counter` is greater than `sizeof( "Beep\n" )` because here is an attempt to access memory beyond the string literal.

Maybe you mean the following

```
cout << "Beep\n" << counter << endl;
```

or

```
cout << "Beep " << counter << endl;
```

In any case there is no need to declare variables `counter` and `trigger` as globals.

Instead of

```
int counter = 0;
int trigger = 0;

int main(){
//...
```

you could write

```
int main(){
    int counter = 0;
    int trigger = 0;
//...
```

Comment: Derp.... Ok I feel stupid. I haven't programmed in c++ for a while.. I was used to C#. But this still seems like a pretty big issue right?

Comment: @user3684557  In C# you may use operator + with strings and integers. In C++ such an operation for character arrays is absent and a string literal is a character array. There is used so-called the pointer arithmetic..